# NGINX ssl upstream verify fail

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxypass

**[UPDATE]**

This [has been raised a a bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1307) with NGINX support.

I have used default config file from the NGINX website (but without two way auth) in order to load balance between four upstream app servers over SSL with the the `proxy_ssl_verify` set to `on`. Yes, All upstream servers have valid certificates with CN matching their hostnames, and CA has been placed on the NGINX server with proper permissions and set in the nginx.conf file. Here are my findings (removed the rest of the config as it is not relevant):

1. OK - Works with `proxy_ssl_verify off`:

   ```
   stream {
         upstream upstream_appsrv{
             server serverA.domain.com:443;
         }
         server {
             listen     8443;
             proxy_pass https://upstream_appsrv;
               (...)
             proxy_ssl  off;
             proxy_ssl_verify off;
         }
   }
   ```
2. NOT OK - As soon as I set `proxy_ssl_verify on` + `proxy_ssl on`:

   ```
   stream {
       upstream upstream_appsrv{
           server serverA.domain.com:443;
       }
       server {
           listen     8443;
           proxy_pass https://upstream_appsrv;
           (...)
           proxy_ssl  on;
           proxy_ssl_verify on;
       }
   }
   ```

NGINX started throwing errors about upstream SSL certificate not matching the backend:`2 upstream SSL certificate does not match "serverB.domain.com" while SSL handshaking to upstream...`Lets change some things and go to the third step.

3. OK! - Now everything works fine:

   ```
   stream {
           upstream serverA.domain.com{
               server serverA.domain.com:443;
           }
           server {
               listen     8443;
               proxy_pass https://serverA.domain.com;
               (...)
               proxy_ssl  on;
               proxy_ssl_verify on;
           }
   }
   ```

Turns out, that not only the `server` definition has to match the CN used in the certificate on the upstream server (obviously) but also the `upstream upstream_appsrv` needs to match the CN! Ok so next step, lets add another upstream server:

4. NOT OK...

   ```
   stream {
           upstream serverA.domain.com{
               server serverB.domain.com:443;
           }
           server {
               listen     8443;
               proxy_pass https://serverA.domain.com;
               (...)
               proxy_ssl  on;
               proxy_ssl_verify on;
           }
   }
   ```

As soon as NGINX connects to the serverB we start seeing same errors again... Even though serverB has got proper CN set matching it's hostname (and is using same CA as serverA) it turns out that NGINX tries to match the CN against the `upstream` definition. And that's the issue I am trying to resolve.

Comment: Proper HTTPS certificate validation consists of checking both that the certificate is signed by a trusted  CA and that the name in the certificate (CN, SAN) matches the domain name used as target.

Comment: In that case how do you loadbalance between four backend servers with SSL and verification?

Comment: I cannot follow your arguments. If it accesses backend1.example.com it will check that the certificate matches exactly this, i.e. backend1.example.com. Same for backend2.example.com etc. If you want to make it to use some other name for the check  configure `proxy_ssl_name` to override the check and SNI extension used to access the server.

Comment: Ok again. I have one nginx that proxies requests to four different backends (loadbalanced). Four different hostnames with four different CNs (serverA.domain.com, serverB.domain.com, serverC.domain.com, serverD.domain.com) and one common CA.  As soon as I set proxy_ssl_verify        on; I get SSL errors in the NGINX error log file. 

My CA wont provide wildcard, nor SAN certs. How do I set this up :)

Comment: If you have a single certificate for the name some-backend.example.com just configure `proxy_ssl_name` to expect exactly this name.

Comment: Your suggestion is for the SNI for one up. I got for backend servers with different IPs different CNs and I need NGINX to verify each certificate, but it seems like NGINX needs upstream [name] to be matching CN which works for the first CN. But as soon as you add another backend, obviously it won't match the CN defined as upstream [name] and it fails. I am waiting for the NGINX support to reply.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have different upstream servers with different DNS names which are using a certificate which neither match their DNS name nor do they share a common name in the certificate so that `proxy_ssl_name` could be used? And using this setup you want still be able to validate the certificates but not in the real way (name+CA) but only in an incomplete way (CA only) which is open for man in the middle attack since all the attacker needs is to have a an arbitrary certificate from the same CA? Looks for me like a broken setup in the first place.

Comment: Show Me where did I write that none of the upstream servers match their DNS name

Comment: If *all* upstream servers would have a certificate matching their DNS name and the name you have used to specify the servers then validation should not be a problem. But, you complain that it fails because it verifies the CN and fails, which means that the CN does not match the name you have configured. Therefore my conclusion is that the DNS name does not match the certificate.

Comment: Or try doing this with two upstreams and you will see what the problem is. If you don't experience any issues please share your config

Comment: Please give me two hours and I will send step by step into

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but before that, have you got any LB set with more than one upstream with SSL verification set? If yes then please tell me what have you got set as upstream name, DNS entry or custom alias like: upstream myapp_upstream

Comment: I did not. I only have lots of knowledge around TLS and what you present here as error message shows a mismatch between DNS name and certificate and what you propose as solution makes it open for man in the middle attacks. It might be useful to have more details in your question, especially what the name in the certificate for each of the upstream servers is compared to the name you've specified in nginx and also the exact error messages you get.

Comment: ok updated the description

Comment: And this is why I do not agree with the complete example here (https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-upstreams/) as NGINX throws an error that the 'backend' does not match. Instead of the 'backend' you should use CN

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description of the problem. Based on this I would say that this is a bug, at least in the version of nginx you are using. If this does not work with the latest version of nginx I would suggest to report it as bug using the details from your question.

Comment: Thanks! ticket raised with the nginx https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1307